# How to retain the value is select2 after form submit in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a `select2` on my view, but when the user clicks submit on the form and the validation fails the previously selected values are cleared.

I tried using `set_select()` but it does not work.

Hoping that someone has encountered the same and had a solution.

Comment: form submits reloads the page if you want to retain the value store it in local storage then set it when page loads

Answer (score 2):

I got it, and for anyone who might benefit this is how I managed to do it:

**On the controller:**

```
 $data['selected_values'] = implode(", ", $this->input->post('nameOfselect2'));
```

and then pass it back to the view.